# Simple rectified voltage regulator not giving enough power

Tags: power-supply, power

I tried to build a simple stabilised voltage supply for basic use to operate a maximum of 2 PC fans (0.15A and 0.45A) and also a 12V DC LED (0.5A) eg: http://www.led-slt.com/Spotlight/139.html.

Using parts I had around, I built a simple circuit based on an ac transformer (WDB4109 with o/p: 16.7Vac), a schotty rectifier STPS30 (giving 25V dc); an 18v zenner to drop the voltage to 18V which are fed to a voltage regulator [L78S12](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000449.pdf), hoping to have a stabilized 12V dc. I've supplied a circuit diagram.
[image]
Without load, I have 18.2V after the zenner and a nice 12V output. When I connected the 0.13A fan, it rotated very very slowly as if there is no power.

Why I have very limited power in this circuit?

For your info, the transformer circuit is as follows: [image]

Comment: The schematic shows a half-wave rectifier... is that really how it's wired?

Comment: Indeed. The secondary needs a center tap, and a 36V rating.

Comment: What is the value of R?  I am guessing it is quite high.

Comment: In the absenceof a centre tapped transformer, a bridge rectifier (4 of those diodes) would work.

Comment: What is the value of the series resistor, and what is the voltage across the Zener with your load connected?

Comment: Brian: yes. Ignacio, you are right, I thought it would work just the same.  HandyHowie:  The series resistor was originally 500ohms. Now I replaced it with a high wattage 50 Ohms and there was a big difference. I connected the 0.48A bulb but the power supply could deliver a max of 0.15A :-( ;  Brian, OK I try and seek a 4pin rectifier in my stuff.   MANY THANKS TO ALL

Comment: OH! it is L78S12.  From the data sheet, I can see that it can tolerate up to 40V input so I may remove the Zenner and see what happens : http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/22628/STMICROELECTRONICS/L78S12.html

Comment: What would one assume to be the power delivered by the transformer (WDB4109). It's quite bulky and I think it can give 3Amps

Comment: Use a heatsink for the regulator if you do that. It will dissipate (25-12)V*0.6A=7.8W if you put it directly after the rectifier (with those two fans as load.

Comment: With 0.5 Amp, your 50 Ohm resistor will drop 25 volts - since you are only starting with 25 volts, that doesn't leave much for the load!  If you remove the resistor and Zener, the regulator will have to drop 13 volts - at 1 Amp, that means it will have to dissipate 13 Watts.  Use a REALLY BIG heatsink!!

Comment: @PeterBennett: I missed the LED. That must be one bright LED (0.5A).

Comment: I think that I need a maximum of 1.5Amp from the circuit if I shall be using a maximum of 2 fans (0.4+0.1=0.5A) and 2 spotlights (2x0.5A).

Comment: In the meantime, I removed the zenner from the circuit (but left the high wattage 50Ohms resistor). The Voltage input to the voltage regulatir is now 22.1V. I connected the LED (normally consuming 0.5A max) and the power dissipated was 0.15A. Why I cannot draw more than 0.15A!

Comment: Do you have a heatsink on the L78 regulator? Is it too hot to touch? It might have shut down. You don't need the resistor without the Zener; they together form a (primitive) regulator.

Comment: Also, you should include those two capacitors recommended in the regulator's datasheet (one on input-to-ground, one one output-to-ground).

Comment: I try to search for the 0.33uf capacitors, but I think those are filters for high-freq spikes or ac components in the input. Still, I try to include them.   I will now bypass the resistor and will report back if I get better power output (so far, max 0.15). P.s. the resistor dropped some 4V giving less effort and heat issues to the voltage regulator. So far, the voltage regulator using the LED bulb as load, became warm to hot but not particularly hot.

Comment: Your question: "Why I cannot draw more than 0.15A!" is probably because the transformer can't supply more current than that without its output bogging down.  Check the spec's for a WDB4109 - if you can find them - and you're probably in for a nasty surprise. :(

Comment: Remove Zener and series Resistor.  You have two regulators with zener and linear voltage regulator.  If you check specs L78S12 can handle 40V input.  Zener is preventing regulator from doing it's job.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, if your drawing is accurate then the bottom diode of the STPS30 isn't being used at all and all you're doing is half-wave rectifying and filtering  the output of the secondary.

With no load on the regulator, (assuming it's a 7812 clone) its output voltage will look like 12 volts, but as soon as a load starts drawing substantial current out of the regulator the drop across R will increase, making the Zener invisible and decreasing the voltage available into, and out of, the regulator.

An easy fix would be to get rid of "R" and the Zener, and to let the regulator do the dirty work, but in order to do that, we need to known what the transformer's secondary looks like

**EDIT:**

Now that we know what the transformer looks like, you're left with a couple of basic choices: Use either pins 5 and 6 or 7 and 9 as the inputs to a full-wave bridge rectifier, then smooth and regulate the output of the bridge to get the 12 volts you need to drive your loads.

If you use the center-tapped 11 volt RMS winding as the input to the bridge, you'll lose about 1.5 volts through the diodes so, if your filter cap is big enough, you'll wind up with about 14 volts into the 7812 clone.

Typically, a 7812 needs about 2 volts of headroom to work properly so, depending on the \$I^2R\$ losses in the transformer, the actual drop across the bridge's diodes and the ESR of the reservoir cap, you could wind up with significant ripple into your load.

On the other hand, if you use the 16 volt winding you could wind up ripple-free, but with something like 21 volts into the 7812 and with the 1.1 ampere load from the fans and the LED, the 7812 will have to drop the difference between 21 volts and 12 volts at 1.1 ampere, which means it'll have to dissipate about:

$$ P = IE = 1.1A \times (21V - 12V) \approx 10 \text{ watts}$$

That's a lot for a 7812 in a TO-220 package to dissipate, and one way to keep from having to use a large heat sink to do it is to use a power resistor in front of the 7812 in order to drop the 21 volts to something the 7812 can more reasonably handle.

**NASTY SURPRISE:**

Becoming suspicious because of the roughly 23VA capacity required of the transformer (13 watts for the load and 10 watts wasted in the regulator) I did a cursory search for the transformer and found that the best it can do is less than 10VA!

I lost the link, but you can probably find it if you Google WDB4109 or GAL4118E-WDB-01, which is the same transformer.

In any case, assuming a decent transformer, here's what your power supply should look like:

[image]

and here's the LTspice circuit list if you want to play around with the circuit:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 852
WIRE -256 48 -368 48
WIRE -160 48 -256 48
WIRE -96 48 -160 48
WIRE 224 48 160 48
WIRE -368 80 -368 48
WIRE -256 80 -256 48
WIRE -704 176 -928 176
WIRE -256 176 -256 144
WIRE -256 176 -624 176
WIRE -928 224 -928 176
WIRE -704 224 -704 176
WIRE -624 224 -624 176
WIRE -160 224 -160 48
WIRE 224 224 224 48
WIRE -672 320 -672 208
WIRE -656 320 -656 208
WIRE -928 352 -928 304
WIRE -736 352 -928 352
WIRE -704 352 -704 304
WIRE -704 352 -736 352
WIRE -624 352 -624 304
WIRE -592 352 -624 352
WIRE -368 352 -368 144
WIRE -368 352 -592 352
WIRE -368 384 -368 352
WIRE -256 384 -256 176
WIRE -736 448 -736 352
WIRE -704 448 -736 448
WIRE -592 448 -592 352
WIRE -592 448 -624 448
WIRE -368 480 -368 448
WIRE -256 480 -256 448
WIRE -256 480 -368 480
WIRE -160 480 -160 288
WIRE -160 480 -256 480
WIRE 32 480 32 144
WIRE 32 480 -160 480
WIRE 224 480 224 304
WIRE 224 480 32 480
WIRE -368 544 -368 480
FLAG -368 544 0
SYMBOL schottky -240 144 R180
WINDOW 3 -63 1 Left 2
WINDOW 0 -38 30 Left 2
SYMATTR Value B520C
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL ind2 -720 208 R0
WINDOW 0 -43 40 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -43 75 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 50
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=,1
SYMBOL voltage -928 208 R0
WINDOW 3 24 104 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 339 50)
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL ind2 -608 208 M0
WINDOW 0 -46 46 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -62 79 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value .229
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL res 208 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName RL
SYMATTR Value 8
SYMBOL res -608 432 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName Rimg
SYMATTR Value 1G
SYMBOL PowerProducts\\LT1085-12 32 48 R0
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL schottky -352 448 R180
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 32 Left 2
SYMATTR Value B520C
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL schottky -352 144 R180
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
WINDOW 0 42 31 Left 2
SYMATTR Value B520C
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL schottky -240 448 R180
WINDOW 3 -65 0 Left 2
WINDOW 0 -37 31 Left 2
SYMATTR Value B520C
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL polcap -176 224 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 1500µ
TEXT -352 512 Left 2 !.tran 1
TEXT -720 144 Left 2 !K1 L1 L2  1
```

Comment: You are right: I think the main issue is the STP30S connecting to a non-centred tap transformer.  Still, would such setup (half wave rect.)  produce only 0.15Amps???

https://www.google.com/search?q=WDB4109&tbm=isch&imgil=LNMxoDBnigemEM%253A%253BVrGvpLoWDphMmM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fmonitor.espec.ws%25252Fsection37%25252Ftopic206254.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=LNMxoDBnigemEM%253A%252CVrGvpLoWDphMmM%252C_&biw=1567&bih=618&usg=__qPqogNIgc-4oBEUmMPAJ8p5i1HA%3D&ved=0CCoQyjdqFQoTCNy-pqeawMgCFQSGLAodYBkLjw&ei=nF4dVtyAJ4SMsgHgsqz4CA#imgrc=_&usg=__qPqogNIgc-4oBEUmMPAJ8p5i1HA%3D

Comment: @MarzTronix: try to scrounge 4 diodes and make a full-bridge rectifier for your 16VAC output. Alternatively, try connecting the STPS30 as a full-wave rectifier on the two 5.4VAC secondaries; you should be getting about 15V DC, which will be marginal for the L78 as input (needs about 3V headroom), but worth a try. Refer to http://www.hammondmfg.com/pdf/5c007.pdf for schematics. Also, how big is your filter capacitor?

Comment: Update: I removed the 50Ohms resistor, hence connected the output of the STPS30 to the input of the Volt. regulator and I managed to get a 0.3A output. The light was flickering - very fast but noticable.

Comment: Filter capacitor is currently 330uF (25V).

Comment: So if at present it seems I can have a max of 0.3A, with a full-wave rectification, should I get twice as much or more?

Comment: News: I've found an RS405 bridge rectifier in an old PC PSU circuit. This is rated 4amps.

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I've now replaced mt STPS30 with a fullwave rectifier, replaced the 330uf/25V capacitor with a 1000uF and 50V one. Output from bridge 22.5V, and a stable 12V from the regulator. I connected the bulb and got a great 0.5A reading with a steady light.  The regulator did not got hot after 2mins operation, but I have a heat sink just in case. So far there was improvement.

Comment: My circuit looks like that now. I have abandoned electronics for at least 3-4 years. I am interested to know what software you used to create those diagrams and what those numbers (LTSPICE) mean?

Comment: @MarzTronix: LTspice 1.   The program is LTspice IV, and it's available, free, at http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/.  It's a schematic editor and a SPICE engine  all rolled into one,  and the numbers are a  circuit list which LTspice generates when you make and save a drawing.   The circuit list is a vanilla ASCII text file, and LTspice saves it with whatever filename you give it, plus a ".asc" extension.

Comment: @MarzTronix: LTspice part 2. Once you download LTspice and install it, it sets itself up in its own folder and associates itself with .asc files so that if you make a drawing and save it, you can always  navigate to that .asc file, wherever it is, and left-click on it, and LTspice's schematic editor will automatically start and bring up the  file as an editable drawing.   Once you're  in the schematic editor and you've got a circuit you want to simulate, all you have to do is click on the running man icon and  probe around the drawing to display the circuit's various waveforms .

Comment: @MarzTronix: LTspice part 3. To use the file I included in my answer, what you'd do would be to copy it and save it as a file with a name of your choosing but with a filename extension of ".asc".  Once that's done, just navigate over to the file, left-click on it , and LTspice will start and display the editable drawing.

Comment: I've dled LTspice IV and i reworked my diagram (but I did not get it simulated due to errors). There much to learn such as the simple task of how to place a transformer, a simple switch, if it is possible to put IC such as the simple STPS30 or RS405 rather then build it up from diodes.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the available transformer taps the best way with the given components would be to use the output from the transformer tappings labelled as 5 and 6. According to the image this would give 16.33 V. Connecting this directly to the linear regulator would still allow a 12 V Output.
However depending on the current your circuit draws the linear regulator could get hot and require additional cooling.

For a more efficient circuit you could use a step-down regulator with a large capacitor in front for smoothing. For example a easy solution from the Traco TSR Series. Furthermore for high current draw a full wave rectification is advisable.

Comment: I am going to replace the STPS30 with a full rectifier RS405. I hope the resulting voltage is not to high for the linear regulator. What smoothing capacitor you suggest after the output of the rectifier. Currently there is a 330uF / 25V but better put a higher V-rating capacitor. PS. In the original circuit I was trying to step down the output viltage by a 18V zenner,

Comment: Question: I have difficulty were to connect the ground of the rectifier, because as shown in my circuit, the DC ground is common with the AC ground, and that would mean a direct short between pin 3 (one of the ac in) and pin 4 (dc -) of the IC

Comment: If you use a bridge rectifier, your circuit ground will be the negative terminal of the bridge.  Neither end of the transformer seconary should be connected to your circuit ground.

Comment: Thanks! I opened the track to isolate the grounds. I just need to buy a smoothing/filter capacitor 1000uF/50V and tell you how it went!

Comment: That smoothing capacitor should improve the input to your linear regulator. Especially as most capacitor technologies have a lower capacitance then what they are labeled as, when they work close to their maximum voltage. The combination of resistor and zener can work, but it needs to be adjusted to the maximum current that could occur to ensure enough voltage at the input to the linear regulator.

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I've Now replaced mt STPS30 with a fullwave rectifier, replaced the 330uf/25V capacitor with a 1000uF and 50V one. Output from bridge 22.5V, and a stable 12V from the regulator. I connected the bulb and got a great 0.5A reading with a steady light.  So far so good!

Comment: Congratulations :) If you have access to an Oscilloscope you could compare the difference between your setups: Look at the voltage curve at the input and output of your linear regulator. You will probably see that in your old layout the voltage at the input drops below the required value. But do not measure mains. Watch the temperature of your linear regulator if you want to use this for a longer time and maybe add a heatsink to it. As your problems seems solved you should select one of the answers as the solution and if you like upvote answers that were helpful.

Comment: Hi, I've connected my loads in parallel, made them switchable and a cute LED on/off indicator. I can have up to about 0.8A but that's fine, I think it is a limitation of the transformer.  I wish to know how to calculate the max power that a transformer can give.

Answer (score 1):

This is how my circuit looks like:
Lessons learnt (solution)

1: high resistor feeding zenner diode was limiting power output on load. When 500Ohms was changed to 50Ohms, there was a drastic improvement.

2: Full wave rectification gives further power output from half wave

3: Smoothing capacitor of 1000uF improves the sc stability

4: Read the specs! The LM7805(equiv) was found to be able and take up to 40V as input so the zenner was useless to step down the 25Vdc output from the rectifier

5: RS405 = Full fave rectifier, 4A

[image: Basic regulated Power Supply for small applications]

Answer (score 0):

Posting just to show you the final stages of the project. I have build an own terranium and wanted some heat regulation. I've ripped many components from an unused microwave, such as the heating elements, power supply, fan and light bulb. The main concern is to maintian a constant temp. The heating elements in their original stated where too hot, hence i have connected them to a triac regulator to lower their output once they heat the chamber to the given value.

One of the ac splits feeds the powersupply, which is used to give 4 switchable 12Vdc outputs to power more internal fans and lights. The vivarium has on ac fan, on ac heating element, one uv light, on cool white light, one bulb light (subtle heat), one dc light and two dc computer fans.

Main issue is to keep a constant temp all over the vivarium!
[enter image description here][1]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad we could help and nice to hear the application. Two final suggestions, as this site behaves different than a normal forum: 1) Select one answer as the accepted answer to show this question is solved. 2) Post updates like this in your initial question or if it fits better in your answer by editing those. Do not create multiple answers. An answer here is meant as a solution to the initial question.